# How to have four of the same custom widget have text change individually?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am looking to create a grid with 4 custom widgets that can either add or subtract from a given starting number. [See image for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BmBt.jpg)
For example, if you press player one, the number would increase or decrease to 100 or 99. But the other 3 players would remain the same.

I had originally used one stateful widget with a separate function for each player, but I am sure there's a way to do it in a more modular way.

```
class CommanderDamage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return CommanderDamageState();
  }
}

class CommanderDamageState extends State<CommanderDamage> {
  int damage = 0;

  void update() {
    setState(() {
      damage++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: GridView.builder(
          gridDelegate:
              SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
          itemCount: 4,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
            return Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Player " + index.toString()),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: update,
                    child: Container(
                        width: 100.0,
                        height: 100.0,
                        child: Text(damage),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT: I have edited my code to reflect my current. Currently, when the damage area is pressed, the damage increases for all 4 players instead of the one I am pressing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of trial and error I managed to find an answer.
I had to set the state within the onTap instead of making a separate  function and calling it in the onTap.

```
class CommanderDamage extends StatefulWidget {
  int damage = 0;
  CommanderDamage({this.damage, Key key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return CommanderDamageState();
  }
}

class CommanderDamageState extends State<CommanderDamage> {
  var damage = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topLeft, end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  colors: [Color(0xfff6921e), Color(0xffee4036)],
                ),
              ),
              child: GridView.builder(
                gridDelegate:
                    SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
                itemCount: damage.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              damage[index]++;
                            });
                          },
                          onLongPress: () {
                            setState(() {
                              damage[index] = 0;
                            });
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            width: 100.0,
                            height: 100.0,
                            child: Text(damage[index].toString()),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your text widget inside InkWell(). Basically what InkWell does is creates a rectangular touch responsive area.

```
InkWell(
    child: Text(
      'Player One',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
      onTap: () {
        // Your function
      }
    )
```

But this make the interactive tap area according to size of the text which is very small, so it's better to wrap it inside a container and provide height-width or some space with padding

```
InkWell(
    child: Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      child: Text(
        'Player One',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white), ),
      onTap: () {
        // Your function
      }
    )
```

An inside onTap you can your function and perform changes.

Read more about InkWell: 
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html

Comment: Not quite, the answer I was looking for, but that is a suggestion that I overlooked. Thanks :)

Comment: You can use a GestureaDetector widget if you want instead of InkWell. What you were looking for?

Comment: I want to use the same custom widget 4 times, but they're functions are independent from each other, for example widget one has text with "40" once its pressed, it will go to 41, but widget two - four will remain at "40"